# How to declare a dynamic link in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

What I want to do is to create a list within another. Example home/4/5/ etc
Also if I want to change the name from path it gives an error saying no reverse.

```
path('findstudent/', views.FindStudent.as_view(), name='findstudent'),
path('findstudent/<int:pk>/', views.FindStudentdetail.as_view(), name='findstudent'),
path('findstudent/<int:pk>/<int:pk_alt>/', views.FindStudentresult.as_view(), name='findstudent'),


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class FindStudent(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/findStudent.html'
    model = Student
    fields = ['sbtc']

    def get_queryset(self):
        batch = Student.objects.values_list('sbtc').distinct()
        return batch

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class FindStudentdetail(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/findStudentdetail.html'
    model = Student
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        student = Student.objects.filter(sbtc=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return student

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class FindStudentresult(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/findStudentresult.html'
    model = Result
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        result1 = Result.objects.select_related('Student')
        result = Result.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk_alt'])
        return result
```

The problem is here:
How can I define the path/url in the template!

```
    <div class="form-group">
                      {% for student in object_list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 

    **'Dashboard:findstudent'**

 %}">{{student.sroll}} {{student.snam}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your URL with this :

carreful you call all your url in the same name !

```
path('findstudent/', views.FindStudent.as_view(), name='findstudent'),
path(r'^findstudent/(?P<int:pk>)/$', views.FindStudentdetail.as_view(), name='findstudent'),
path(r'^findstudent/(?P<int:pk>)/(?P<int:pk_alt>)/$', views.FindStudentresult.as_view(), name='findstudentTemplate'),


{% for student in object_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'findstudentTemplate' student.sroll student.snam %}"></a></li>
            {% endfor %}
```